# Using VBOs in python

Tags: python, opengl

Im trying to optimize my opengl app using VBOs, right now it works perfectly using vertex arrays but when I use VBOs in doesn't render anything neither throws any exception. All the tutorials I've seen use similar approaches.
Here is the code to upload and to render those VBOs.

```
    def uploadToVRAM(self):
    usage = GL_STATIC_DRAW
    if self.vertices_VBO == None:
        self.vertices_VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices_VBO)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ADT.arrayByteCount(self.vertices), ADT.voidDataPointer(self.vertices), usage)
    #glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices, usage)
    #print "Bytes:",ADT.arrayByteCount(self.vertices)

    if self.normals != None:
        if self.normals_VBO == None:
            self.normals_VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.normals_VBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ADT.arrayByteCount(self.normals), ADT.voidDataPointer(self.normals), usage)
        #glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.normals, usage)

    if self.colors != None:
        if self.colors_VBO == None:
            self.colors_VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.colors_VBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ADT.arrayByteCount(self.colors), ADT.voidDataPointer(self.colors), usage)
        #glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.colors, usage)

    if self.uvs != None:
        if self.uvs_VBO == None:
            self.uvs_VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.uvs_VBO)
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ADT.arrayByteCount(self.uvs), ADT.voidDataPointer(self.uvs), usage)
        #glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.uvs, usage)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0)
```

And this is the rendering part:

```
    def renderVBOs(self, primitive):
        #active arrays
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertices_VBO)
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0) #offset in bytes

        if self.normals != None:
            glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.normals_VBO)
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0, 0)

        if self.colors != None:
            glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.colors_VBO)
            glColorPointer(4,GL_FLOAT,0, 0 )

        if self.uvs != None:
            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.uvs_VBO)
            glTexCoordPointer(2,GL_FLOAT,0, 0 )
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,0)

        #render    
        glDrawArrays(primitive, 0, self.num_vertex)

        #clear
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)            
        if self.normals != None:
            glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        if self.colors != None:
            glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        if self.uvs != None:
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB,0)
```

Comment: The only thing I see is the call to glGenBuffers. The real GL function works like glGenBuffers(count, *buffers) but I assume in Python your code works.

Answer (score 0):

By looking over your code I notice one possible and one probable problem:

1. In your data upload you don't use the ARB variants of GL constants (like you do for rendering)
2. You unbind your array buffer before you call `glDrawArrays`

If this doesn't help try making a minimal runnable example we can play with to make it work.

Comment: I tryed both things and didnt work. The ARBs where because i changed that couple of times, the unbind is because I dont want to use any VBO for the indices. I will try to make a minimal version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both points do not matter, as the array binding is only used in gl...Pointer calls and the constants usually have the same value (at least in this extension).